How JQ6500 16P V2.1 play sound by index
image of a JQ6500 board
How to play by index please tell me
my code:
from jq6500 import Player
from machine import UART

uart = UART(1, baudrate=9600, tx=39, rx=37)

p = Player(port=1)
p.set_volume(30)

p.play_by_index(2)


What happens when you run your code? What device are you running MicroPython on and have you verified that it's communicating with the JQ6500 board at all?
